# Is it safe to run in stability shoes if you have neutral feet?

Tags: running

I always wore neutral and was ok. Now bought Adidas Solarboost 19 ST on promotion cause I wasn't aware of these topics at the time of buying and im afraid if I won't hurt myself? Still haven't used them to run so I have the option to return but then maybe it's not really needed and I can use them with no problems ?

Not sure how these stability shoes work, I saw a youtube review of regular (non-ST) Solarboost 19 by kofuzi and they seem to look identical to stability edition.

These are my first serious running shoes, so far I have used Adidas Duramo 7 and love them cause they are super comfortable, now wanted to have something with even better softness to be able to run longer and more often.